# differences between using compiled code and PHP accelerators for performance

Tags: php, c++, performance, apc, phalcon

- Recently I read about PhalconPHP. In some rankings of framework phalcon is first, and it's because phalcon is written as a C-extension and it means the code isn’t interpreted because is already compiled.

  so we save **one step**! It's good!
- On the other hand we do have accelerators in PHP, Most PHP accelerators work by caching the compiled opcode/bytecode of PHP representation of php files to avoid the overhead of parsing and compiling source code on each request.

  again, we save **one step**!

  The questions are:

  1.what's the differences between these two in
  performance not at architect?

  2.should we choose one of them,is not it something called rework?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that a tool like APC compiles the code to native machine code like Phalcon?

Answer (score 0):

Questions about performance without specific use cases are a bit vague for this site, consider adding examples of what you are trying to achieve. Any performance gain from any system will depend heavily on the code, database, schema etc etc.

That being said my personal experience with Phalcon is very positive. I rewrote a Zend Framework v1 / Doctrine 2 CMS in phalcon and some page builds up to 10x faster, with up to 70% reduction in reported memory usage. I don't plan on every going back to a pure PHP framework if I can help it.

And yes I was using opcode caching for the ZF/D code. In fact I still use it for the phalcon codebase, it is not either/or!

Answer (score 0):

PHP cached with APC is still iterpreted, for example like Java is, so native code is faster for many common use-cases.